# Update Product: http_status_message => Not Found, but product DOES exist

Tags: shopify

I'm having issues with the "PUT" method for updating products. I'm getting the 404 which I've read means the product does not exist, though it definitely does. I have successfully added products so I know my connection is good.

Currently, my scope is set to do everything I could find: *and will back it off after dev is done.*

```
var $scope = "write_products,write_content,write_themes,write_customers,write_orders,write_script_tags,write_shipping";
```

The api shows the update url as: **/admin/products/#123456789.json**
http://api.shopify.com/product.html#update

I'm using the "ohShpify" PHP API adapter. *I would ask them questions on GitHub but it looks like they have the comments and wiki turned off.*
https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php/blob/master/shopify.php

**For those who are interested in looking at the class:**

```
<?php class ShopifyClient {
public $shop_domain;
private $token;
private $api_key;
private $secret;
private $last_response_headers = null;

public function __construct($shop_domain, $token, $api_key, $secret) {
    $this->name = "ShopifyClient";
    $this->shop_domain = $shop_domain;
    $this->token = $token;
    $this->api_key = $api_key;
    $this->secret = $secret;
}

// Get the URL required to request authorization
public function getAuthorizeUrl($scope, $redirect_url='') {
    $url = "http://{$this->shop_domain}/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={$this->api_key}&scope=" . urlencode($scope);
    if ($redirect_url != '')
    {
        $url .= "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url);
    }
    return $url;
}

// Once the User has authorized the app, call this with the code to get the access token
public function getAccessToken($code) {
    // POST to  POST https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token
    $url = "https://{$this->shop_domain}/admin/oauth/access_token";
    $payload = "client_id={$this->api_key}&client_secret={$this->secret}&code=$code";
    $response = $this->curlHttpApiRequest('POST', $url, '', $payload, array());
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    if (isset($response['access_token']))
        return $response['access_token'];
    return '';
}

public function callsMade()
{
    return $this->shopApiCallLimitParam(0);
}

public function callLimit()
{
    return $this->shopApiCallLimitParam(1);
}

public function callsLeft($response_headers)
{
    return $this->callLimit() - $this->callsMade();
}

public function call($method, $path, $params=array())
{
    $baseurl = "https://{$this->shop_domain}/";

    $url = $baseurl.ltrim($path, '/'); 
    $query = in_array($method, array('GET','DELETE')) ? $params : array(); 
    $payload = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? stripslashes(json_encode($params)) : array();
    $request_headers = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", 'Expect:') : array();

    // add auth headers
    $request_headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: ' . $this->token;

    $response = $this->curlHttpApiRequest($method, $url, $query, $payload, $request_headers);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    if (isset($response['errors']) or ($this->last_response_headers['http_status_code'] >= 400))
        throw new ShopifyApiException($method, $path, $params, $this->last_response_headers, $response);

    return (is_array($response) and (count($response) > 0)) ? array_shift($response) : $response;
}

private function curlHttpApiRequest($method, $url, $query='', $payload='', $request_headers=array())
{
    $url = $this->curlAppendQuery($url, $query);
    $ch = curl_init($url); 
    $this->curlSetopts($ch, $method, $payload, $request_headers); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    $errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($errno) throw new ShopifyCurlException($error, $errno);
    list($message_headers, $message_body) = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $response, 2);
    $this->last_response_headers = $this->curlParseHeaders($message_headers);

    return $message_body;
}

private function curlAppendQuery($url, $query)
{
    if (empty($query)) return $url;
    if (is_array($query)) return "$url?".http_build_query($query);
    else return "$url?$query";
}

private function curlSetopts($ch, $method, $payload, $request_headers)
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'HAC');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    if (!empty($request_headers)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

    if ($method != 'GET' && !empty($payload))
    {
        if (is_array($payload)) $payload = http_build_query($payload);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    }
}

private function curlParseHeaders($message_headers)
{
    $header_lines = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $message_headers);
    $headers = array();
    list(, $headers['http_status_code'], $headers['http_status_message']) = explode(' ', trim(array_shift($header_lines)), 3);
    foreach ($header_lines as $header_line)
    {
        list($name, $value) = explode(':', $header_line, 2);
        $name = strtolower($name);
        $headers[$name] = trim($value);
    }

    return $headers;
}

private function shopApiCallLimitParam($index)
{
    if ($this->last_response_headers == null)
    {
        throw new Exception('Cannot be called before an API call.');
    }
    $params = explode('/', $this->last_response_headers['http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit']);
    return (int) $params[$index];
}   } 
class ShopifyCurlException extends Exception { }
class ShopifyApiException extends Exception {
protected $method;
protected $path;
protected $params;
protected $response_headers;
protected $response;

function __construct($method, $path, $params, $response_headers, $response)
{
    $this->method = $method;
    $this->path = $path;
    $this->params = $params;
    $this->response_headers = $response_headers;
    $this->response = $response;

    parent::__construct($response_headers['http_status_message'], $response_headers['http_status_code']);
}

function getMethod() { return $this->method; }
function getPath() { return $this->path; }
function getParams() { return $this->params; }
function getResponseHeaders() { return $this->response_headers; }
function getResponse() { return $this->response; }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `#` character from your product ID.

It's in the docs because it's pseudo-ruby syntax, so `/admin/products/#{id}.json` translates to `/admin/products/123456789.json`.

Comment: I tried that as well. I tried a few configuration just to test it. All come back the same.

Comment: I found the issue with my code.

I was adding the "metafields" array to the product that was to be updated. Apparently there is something about updating "metafields" that it can not be done at the same time.

I guess I'll possibly be making two calls per update rather than one.